# I'm trying to relate C++ reference to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Before saying it would be a duplicate question and downvote (as it happened before), I searched and found nothing alike.
I, like many others, am trying to learn the uses of C++ reference variables and to relate them to pointers. I found it easier to make a table and I need to know whether it needs to be amended.

```
                   int *n   int n    int &n    caller/local
void foo(int *n)     n       &n        &n          caller
void foo(int n)     *n        n         n           local
void foo(int &n)    *n        n         n          caller
```

The table wants to reflect all legal passed parameters.

```
[1,1]: passing by reference (trivial)  
[1,2]: passing by reference  
[1,3(1)]: passing by reference, an is an address(?)  
[1,3(2)]: passing by reference, as n is used as alias(?)  
[2,1]: passing by value, as dereferencing  
[2,2]: passing by value (trivial)  
[2,3(1)]: passing by value, using value of n (where n is an alias)  
[2,3(2)]: passing by value (dereferencing n, which is an address)  
[3,1(1)]: passing by reference, as foo accepts address  
[3,1(2)]: passing by reference, reference of value at address n  
[3,2(1)]: passing by reference (trivial)  
[3,2(2)]: passing by reference, as foo accepts address or reference  
[3,3]: passing by reference (trivial, as argument matches parameter exactly)
```

1. Are the table and explanations correct?
2. Are there any cases left out of the table (except for derived ones like *&n, pointer to pointer etc.)?

Comment: Only `void foo(int &n)` does pass by reference, the others are all pass by value.

Comment: +1 for C++ newbie's hard-study

Comment: Can you clarify which cell each of your comments is referring to? (e.g., [row, col]?)

Comment: Thank you all for answering. It's [row, col(subcol)].  By pass by reference I meant that the function can modify the "outter scope" variable.

Comment: @mireazma: You're also missing rvalue references: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function

```
void foo(int& n);
```

does *not* accept an address (a pointer), and not literals either.

So you can't call it like

```
int a = ...;
foo(&a);  // Trying to pass a pointer to a function not taking a pointer
```

or

```
foo(1);  // Passing R-value is not allowed, you can't have a reference to a literal value
```

There is an exception though, if you have a constant reference, like

```
int foo(const int& n);
```

then literal values are allowed, because then the referenced value can't be changed.

---

Likewise for

```
void foo(int* n);
```

you *must* pass a pointer.

So for example:

```
int a = ...;
int& ra = a;   // ra references a

foo(&a);  // OK
foo(&ra); // OK
foo(a);   // Fail, a is not a pointer
foo(ra);  // Fail, ra is not a pointer
foo(1);   // Fail, the literal 1 is not a pointer
```

---

And for the last:

```
void foo(int n);
```

With examples:

```
int a = ...;
int& ra = a;   // ra references a
int* pa = &a;  // pa points to a

foo(a);   // OK, the value of a is copied
foo(ra);  // OK, the value of the referenced variable is copied
foo(*pa); // OK, dereferences the pointer, and the value is copied
foo(pa);  // Fail, passing a pointer to a function not expecting a pointer
foo(1);   // OK, the literal value 1 is copied
```

Comment: You should mention `const` references which *do* accept literals.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought pointer &a would function the same as &a reference, obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Overloaded `operator*` and `operator&`

Both `operator&` (unary) and `operator*` (unary) can be overloaded.

This means that if `n` is a class type `type`, then `*n` can literally have any form including, but not limited to `type*`, `type&`, `type`.

An example (stupid, but still a valid example) would be:

```
struct type {
    int x;
};

int& operator&(type& t) {
    return t.x;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b9fd20b77add03c)

### Indirection

You can also have infinite number of pointer indirections. In which case `*n`, `**n`, `***n` might also yield `Type*` as well as `Type&`.

As an example, given two functions:

```
void func_ptr(int*) {}
void func_ref(int&) {}
```

and the following objects:

```
int a;
int* b = &a;
int** c = &b;
int*** d = &c;
```

then, any of the following is valid:

```
func_ptr(b);
func_ptr(*c);
func_ptr(**d);

func_ref(*b);
func_ref(**c);
func_ref(***d);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaca7f7333689208)

### Conclusion

> Are the table and explanations correct? Are there any cases left out of the table (except for derived ones like *&n, pointer to pointer etc.)?

Therefore the table not only is incomplete, but cannot possibly contain all possible cases.

Comment: Nice thing the online sandbox. I'm confused by `type() : x(0) {}`: it looks like it has the role of a constructor. I'd very much want to know what it means.

Comment: @mireazma It's a default constructor `type()`, which has an initializer list `x(0)`, which initializes the member object `x` by passing `0` to its constructor. The body of the default constructor is empty `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm interpreting your table wrong, but assuming you're inside the three functions on the left, and want to get an `int*` to `n`, use `n`, and bind a reference to the `int` value accessed via `n` respectively:

***Your original table***

```
                   int *n   int n   int &n
void foo(int *n)     n       &n      n/&n
void foo(int n)     *n       n      n/*n
void foo(int &n)    n/*n     n/&n      n
```

Given the function signatures on the left, you have the following mistakes:

In `foo(int* n)`:

- to get an `int` you want `*n` ***not*** `&n`
- you must bind any new `int&`s to `*n`

In `foo(int n)`

- to get a pointer to `n` you want `&n` ***not*** `*n`
- to bind an `int&` to `n` you want `n`, ***not*** `*n`
- do note that `n` is a local, copied and different from the caller's `n`

In `foo(int& n)`:

- to get a pointer to `n` you want `&n` ***not*** `n` or `*n`
- to use `n` you just want `n` ***not***/***never*** `&n`

So, I'd write the table like this (I've appended columns for address of `n` and whether `n` is the `n` from the calling context or a local copy)

***Suggested corrected table***

```
                    int*   int    int& n2 = ...    int* p = ...   caller/local
void foo(int* p_n)   p_n   *p_n      *p_n            p_n             caller
void foo(int n)      &n     n         n              &n              local
void foo(int& n)     &n     n         n              &n              caller
```

I'm not convinced such a table has much utility in clarifying the role of references and pointers though.

UPDATE: your comment explains you wanted the table to communicate the "passing form", which I take to be the code you'd need inside the caller of `foo`.  The correct table for that should be:

```
                   int *n   int n   int &n    caller/local
void foo(int *n)     n       &n      &n          caller
void foo(int n)     *n       n       n           local
void foo(int &n)    *n       n       n           caller
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now thanks to you and Joachim Pileborg. I have a confusion, though: elements represent how they should be declared? In my table the declaration is completely as col name and the elements represent the passing form.

Comment: @mireazma: "represent the passing form" - ahhh, that explains why I found your table confusing, and you mine! ;-)  My table shows the form to use the passed parameter inside the function: i.e. the type of local variable you could put in to the function body and initialise using the function parameter.  For example, in `foo(int* p_n) { int* p_n2 = p_n; int n = *p_n; int& n2 = *p_n; int* p = p-N; }` - local variables of those types can be initialised using the expressions in the column.  I'll add another table for correct "passing form".

Comment: @mireazma: ok, and looks good here (but as a general Stack Overflow principle - keep in mind that sometimes when you edit the question (rather than say append an update) it can unfairly render some existing comments and answers invalid or non-sensical and annoy those trying to help you).  Cheers.

Comment: I found my table already edited (removed the wrong entries). I only added caller/local column as it was just the missing clarification.

Comment: I don't like others being able to edit my posts w/o my consent. As a side note it took my a quarter of hour to figure out why I couldn't post the question: SE thought I was righting code, just because I used "[1,2]", "where", "using". It's natural language, not code at all and even if it were, I take full responsibility for what I type and it's my right that it's understood as *I* want it; my writing is my property. Well, it's not about you, Tony, obviously.

Comment: @mireazma: oh - I don't like people editing my posts much either - it's really hit and miss whether it's helpful/correct.  I've only posted a few questions - had no idea the website tried to check the content in any way at all - that's bizarre....